# Gratis for business use, portable, very basic, schedulable, backup program for Windows

Tags: windows, gratis, backup, portable

I think that the tile says it all; I am looking for a [gratis](/questions/tagged/gratis) for business use, [portable](/questions/tagged/portable), very basic, schedulable, [backup](/questions/tagged/backup) program for Windows.

It will run once per day and backup two small directories totalling 50mB. No further features are needed.

Comment: Simply ZIP it? There are many ZIP applications available. Would those suffice?

Comment: Why bother compressing 50mB? And how do I automate moving it?

Comment: Ah! Did we just discover another requirement? Your question didn't speak of automation :) But AFAIK you could use CMD or Powershell with "placeholders" to create a file like `backup_YYYYMMDD.zip` and use the copy/move commands to put it where you like. Let me guess: you don't want to keep backups eternally, but only the last N (one more requirement)? For 365 it's easy by naming it `backup-DOY.zip` (DayOfYear), for weekly `*DOW*` etc. so you have a "ring buffer" (the oldest file gets overwritten). As for compression: I didn't say so. Simply "store" (1 file per backup, easier to handle).

Comment: Just backup capability, no restore functionality?

Comment: Where do you want to backup to? USB Stick, Cloud, FTP? A backup on the local disk is not a backup. No GUI needed? Is a command line tool fine?

Comment: "A backup on the local disk is not a backup" - I want to copy Virtual Machine data to the shared folder. then back it up on the host o/s, in case I lose the VM. I may as well just schedule an `XCOPY`, I guess

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is use the windows built in "Task Scheduler"

Open control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Task Scheduler.

You can create any simple repeatable task to fire at any time you'd like, such as 4:00 am when you're otherwise not using the machine.

I've used this before for this very purpose, copy active work to some place every night just in case the next day is one of those "everything I touch turns to crap" days - which happens...

Hope that works for you

Comment: I wanted to do this all along, but was asked for an app. Yup, I will go with the Task Scheduler and XCOPY. Welcome aboard. I look forward to seeing you help more people in future :-)

Comment: I'm.kkinimoo r m.

Comment: Is this some kind of covfefe? Are we supposed to understand it?

Comment: Oops - looks like I butt-dialed StackExchange :)